# How to alter relationship keeping existing data in entity framework code first?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have two entities

```
public class Account
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set;
        public int MemberInfoId { get; set; }
        public Member MemberInfo { get; set; }
        //Other Properties
    }

public class Member
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        //Other Properties
    }
```

With following relationship

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
                .HasRequired(a => a.MemberInfo)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(a => a.MemberInfoId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

However, an Account has one Member only so the following relation is better suited (I guess)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
                .HasRequired(a => a.MemberInfo)
                .WithRequiredPrincipal()
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

But code first migration won’t migrate to that. It gives the following error

> ```
> The object 'PK_dbo.Members' is dependent on column 'Id'.
> The object 'FK_dbo.Accounts_dbo.Members_MemberInfo_Id' is dependent on column 'Id'.
> ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN Id failed because one or more objects access this column.
> ```

What can I do to alter the relation without recreating the database to keep the already inserted data?

Comment: are you using automatic migrations? for something like this you might need to create a custom code-based migration

Comment: @jjj - Yes I am using automatic migrations.

Comment: Shouldn't the `Member` be the principal, since the member has an account? So `Entity<Account>().HasRequiredPrincipal(a => a.MemberInfo).WithRequired()`. You might still need a custom migration though, but at least it wouldn't be trying to drop your `Member.Id` column.

Comment: @jjj -There are other entities connected to Account and Member which I haven’t added here. With those other entities in Account it helps to cascade delete member when I delete an account.

Comment: @jjj I’m sorry may be I am not aware about this but “HasRequiredPrincipal” is totally unkown to me. Could you tell me what namespace should I use.

Comment: oops, i meant to say `Entity<Account>().HasRequired(a => a.MemberInfo).WithRequiredDependent()`, but that would make the member side the principal side, which it sounds like you don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can read [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj554735.aspx) on mixing code-based migrations with automatic migrations to see if you even want to go this route in the first place. Generally, it's not a good idea if you have a team involved.

Next, it might be good to know that if you change the relationship between `Member` and `Account` to a one-to-one, Entity Framework requires that the primary key on the dependent side also be the foreign key. The column that used to be the primary key on the dependent side will become useless from EF's perspective. You also won't need the `Account.MemberInfoId` anymore, either.

Finally to create a migration, *after* you finish modifying the models, you can run `Add-Migration` with a migration name. This will create a migration file with a `DbMigration` class that you can modify. You'll probably need to do something like the following:

- Create a new column in `Member` that will hold the new foreign key
- Use `Sql()` to update values in that column with the primary key of the associated account
- Drop the foreign key constraint, index, and primary key
- Drop the account.memberinfo_id column and member.id column (which is optional, but if you don't drop the member.id column, you'll have to make sure to map the model's `Member.Id` property to the column created above).
- Rename new column in member to id
- Add primary key to new column in `Member`
- Add index and foreign key

I'm sure I've missed something, but that's the general gist. I'd probably also backup everything, since something's guaranteed to go wrong the first five times or so.

Comment: Thank you very much. As you have said automatic migration won’t work, I think the steps you have listed are the only way.